# Error while setting a Datacontext for a UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I have usercontrol where I am trying to set the `DataContext` as below:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" Path="MyViewModel">

    </Binding>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Here `dataGrid` is a child `DataGrid` control and `MyViewModel` is my `ViewModel` class. Currently its giving following error while runtime:

`Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=dataGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=MyViewModel; DataItem=null; target element is 'UserControl1' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')`

Can anyone please help what is the problem here?

Comment: You can find an answer in this StackOverflow answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9122644/2342414

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely due to Name Scoping constraints. ElementName Bindings only work properly within defined boundaries. This specific error is saying that it can't find the named element "dataGrid". Can you show more of the surrounding XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Is MyViewModel set on the DataContext of dataGrid?

If so change MyViewModel in Path to DataContext and you are good to go...
If not, set your MyViewModel class to DataContext and remove the ElementName from the Binding, and it should work as well ;)

Comment: error states that binding cannot find `source` for property, not the property itself. Though I believe next step it won't find a property :)

Answer (score 0):

This binding tries to access `dataGrid.MyViewModel`, but `MyViewModel` is not a property of the `DataGrid`... You should do something like that instead :

```
<Binding ElementName="dataGrid" Path="DataContext.MyViewModel">
```