# Custom Layout Control and the Logical Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I've been working on a control for a while that can be used to repeat a layout in our application. It's working great but the problem is that the controls inside the layout control aren't participating in the logical tree.

It's a custom control with a left header, a right header a body and a standard footer.

**Generic.xaml:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FrameControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:FrameControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Background="LightGray"/>

                        <DockPanel Background="{TemplateBinding HeaderColor}">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding HeaderLeftContent}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>

                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding HeaderRightContent}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="40" 
                                                    Margin="5, 5, 5, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DockPanel>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,49,0,0" Background="White">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding BodyContent}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <DockPanel Background="White" Margin="5"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Border>
                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="0" Background="LightGray"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**FrameControl.cs**

```
public class FrameControl : Control
{
    public Brush HeaderColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(HeaderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(FrameControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public Collection<Object> HeaderLeftContent
    {
        get { return (Collection<Object>)GetValue(HeaderLeftContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderLeftContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderLeftContentProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderLeftContent", typeof(Collection<Object>), typeof(FrameControl),
       new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public Collection<Object> HeaderRightContent
    {
        get { return (Collection<Object>)GetValue(HeaderRightContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderRightContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderRightContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderRightContent", typeof(Collection<Object>), typeof(FrameControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public Collection<Object> BodyContent
    {
        get { return (Collection<Object>)GetValue(BodyContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BodyContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BodyContent", typeof(Collection<Object>), typeof(FrameControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    static FrameControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FrameControl)));
    }

    public FrameControl()
    {
        SetValue(HeaderLeftContentProperty, new Collection<Object>());
        SetValue(HeaderRightContentProperty, new Collection<Object>());
        SetValue(BodyContentProperty, new Collection<Object>());
    }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
   <fc:FrameControl>
        <fc:FrameControl.HeaderLeftContent>
            <Label Content="Left content of the header"/>
        </fc:FrameControl.HeaderLeftContent>
        <fc:FrameControl.HeaderRightContent>
                <Button>
                <TextBlock Text="Example button"/>
            </Button>
                <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Filter A"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Filter B"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Filter C"/>
                </ComboBox>
        </fc:FrameControl.HeaderRightContent>
        <fc:FrameControl.BodyContent>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Content="name"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Type name"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />

                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Keyword"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Parameter"/>

                <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Width"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Height"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="..."/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="="/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="&lt;"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="&gt;"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </fc:FrameControl.BodyContent>
    </fc:FrameControl>
```

I've tried using different type of properties to hold the elements for the different region like UIElementCollection but that made no difference. I also tried manually adding the controls to the logical tree, but I did not succeed in that. Am I missing something?

Comment: What makes you think that *the controls inside the layout control aren't participating in the logical tree*? That's a bold statement. What exactly *is* your problem?

Comment: The main problem I have with this is that I cannot bind using ElementName with this control. Elements that are inside the FrameControl cannot be approached this way. Binding with Source={x:Reference NameOfElement} does work, but gives design time errors. Making it impossible to use the designer. The answers to this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122592/elementname-binding-is-failing) gave me the idea that my control doesn't add its children to the logical tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that your *actual* problem is that you *cannot bind using ElementName with this control. Elements that are inside the FrameControl cannot be approached this way.* However, that problem has absolutely nothing to do with the visual tree. Those elements *are* in the visual tree, but you just can't access them because they were defined inside a `ControlTemplate`.

You can use the [`ControlTemplate.FindName` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to 'find' the elements for you. However, you need to have an element that the `ControlTemplate` has been applied to and a named element in the `ControlTemplate`:

```
// Assuming that your DockPanel in the ControlTemplate was named DockPanel
DockPanel dockPanel = 
    frameControl.Template.FindName("DockPanel", frameControl) as DockPanel;
if (dockPanel != null) // You must check for null
{
    DoSomethingHereWith(dockPanel);
}
```

See the linked page for more help.

Comment: Ah! I understand. Then I guess an ItemsControl as a container for controls is not the right way if I want to use it as a panel with 3 sections. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. In WPF, we work with *data* and after defining `DataTemplate`s for that data, we just let the Framework take care of rendering the UI controls for us.