# ElementName binding doesn't resolve properties

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, resharper, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

When I bind something to the `SelectedItem` of a ListView using `ElementName`, the properties cannot be resolved.

I can still build and run my app, but because of this error I'm not sure that I didn't make any typo's.

I read and tried the answer given in [ElementName Binding is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122592/elementname-binding-is-failing) but `Source={x:Reference ...}` doesn't seem to exist in the WinRT framework.

### Just an example:

My page has a property `MyContainerObject` with an `IEnumerable<MyParentObject>` inside called `MyParents`. Each `MyParentObject` has an `IEnumerable<MyChildObject>` called `MyChildren` inside.

The DataContext of my page:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I have ListView with the following XAML properties:

- `x:Name = "FirstListView"`
- `ItemsSource = {Binding MyContainerObject.MyParents}`

Then I have another ListView with the following XAML properties:

- `x:Name = "SecondListView"`
- `ItemsSource = "{Binding SelectedItem.MyChildren, ElementName=FirstListView}"`

Now ReSharper gives me the following warning:

```
Cannot resolve property 'MyChildren' in data context of type 'object'.
```

Comment: Tried using an IValueConverter but the return type of Convert() is also object so that didn't work. https://twitter.com/WesleyCabus/status/491529341424390145

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your listview:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance model:MyParentObject}"
```