# WPF databinding error in Tag property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:son"
         x:Class="son.SonWindow">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
        <Grid.Tag>
            <Label Content="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=myGrid}" />
        </Grid.Tag>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Just as a simple code above, but the binding cannot find the Element myGrid. During runtime, the error is shown in the Output window

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=myGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Content' (type 'Object')"

I am using Visual Studio 2015 community version with .Net Framework 4.5.2. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you wrapping a Label inside the Tag property? If you move the Label element outside the Tag it works.

Comment: @benPearce ya.. I understand that just removing the tag will make it work, but I am wondering why the above code will generate a Error. I just want to figure out whether the error is related to something special of the Tag property.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The element (whose property is bound) should be part of the visual tree so that the visual tree search can be done. When using Binding with `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`, it performs some internal visual tree search. But in your code the `Label` is disconnected from visual tree by the `Tag`. `Label` is just an object in memory, referenced by the Tag property.

Since .NET 4.0 you can use the `{x:Reference}` markup instead, like this:

```
<Grid.Tag>
    <Label Content="{Binding ActualWidth, Source={x:Reference myGrid}}" />
</Grid.Tag>
```

**Edit**:

Using `{x:Reference}` can cause issue of cyclic dependency if the reference name points to some element containing the `{x:Reference}`. In your case it is `myGrid` (containing `{x:Reference}`). So it cannot be used in your case. Instead you need to use some proxy. This technique seems a bit hacky but in fact it's very pretty. It also surely works in any version of .NET (supporting WPF):

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding ElementName=myGrid}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Tag>
        <Label Content="{Binding Value.ActualWidth, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
    </Grid.Tag>
</Grid>
```

As you see the Binding works with its `Source` set to `StaticResource` pointing to a `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`. This is a `Freezable` object so it's quite interesting that all Bindings set for any DependencyProperty of a `Freezable` object work well no matter you use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`. So we bind its `Value` property to the `Grid` (with name of `myGrid`). Later on we bind the `Content` property of `Label` to the `Freezable` object but with `Path` set to `Value.ActualWidth` (`Value` points to `Grid`, so we need to append `ActualWidth` to bind it to `Grid.ActualWidth`).

In fact you can use any `Freezable` object but we use `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` for convenience, its `Value` accepts all kinds of `object`.

There is another technique to set Binding in a situation like this (disconnected context) but it requires you to create a custom `MarkupExtension`. It's of course more complicated (but still simple enough once you're familiar with WPF).

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I replace my code with yours. However, during design time, I got an error **object reference not set to an instance of an object**. And during run time, an exception is shown in the Output window.

Comment: The exception is Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Cannot call MarkupExtension.ProvideValue because of a cyclical dependency. Properties inside a MarkupExtension cannot reference objects that reference the result of the MarkupExtension. The affected MarkupExtensions are:
'System.Windows.Data.Binding' Line number '7' and line position '20'.

Comment: @JuniverHazoic sorry, I did not notice the cyclic issue, please see my edit for another solution.

Comment: Fantastic solution!!! Thank you very much. I think now I have a better understanding of visual tree and get a workaround to deal with similar scenarios as above.

Comment: Fantastic in the sense that it helped me; not at all fantastic in the sense that I went through many iterations and about 2 hours trying to figure out how to add a friggin tooltip.  This proves xaml is an anti-pattern.  No presentation system should ever be this over-complicated.

Comment: This little bit saved me..."{Binding ElementName=MyGrid}".  There are other solutions but they all assume "{Binding}" will do the trick.  None of them worked for me.  Thanks so much....

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code snippet in WPF and its working fine.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.Tag>
        <Label Content="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=myGrid}" />
    </Grid.Tag>
</Grid>
```

Comment: this code looks exactly like the OP's, so you should provide some info about your environment, such as version of .NET, how did you know it works? The only reason this could work is in the latest version of .NET  it may behave differently (improved). At least in .NET 4.5 (and earlier versions) this won't work.

Comment: i tried your code snippet in WPF, but during runtime the Output window again give the same error as above.

Comment: I tested this in VS2010 WPF application (.Net Framework 4.0). I am able to see window without any binding errors when I ran my application.

Answer (score 0):

I have also try to replicate issue but below code is working fine in VS 2010.

```
<Window x:Class="CustomEventHandlerClick.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomEventHandlerClick"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
        <Grid.Tag>
            <Label Content="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=myGrid}"/>
        </Grid.Tag>
    </Grid>
   </Grid>
```