# In a datagrid, how do you bind a different ItemsSource for each row when also using a CompositeCollection?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid, compositecollection

I have a DataGrid where the ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```

Each item in the ObservableCollection also has an ObservableCollection of strings.

One of the columns is a DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a ComboBox.  I would like each row's ComboBox to contain items in the ObservableCollection of strings in that row's ViewModel.  If I bind it normally, this works.  However, I can't seem to get it to work if I am using a CompositeCollection.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column Title">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding ???}" />
                        <ComboBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.EditList, Source={x:Reference myGridName}}">Edit List</Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I'm not sure what to use for the Binding to get it to work.  Without the CompositeCollection, I can simply do:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
```

In searching, I know you need to set a source for the CollectionContainer, but most examples were for setting it to a static list that's the same for all rows.  I need each row to bind to the ObservableCollection in that row's ViewModel.

I've tried:

```
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.SubItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" />
```

But that results in an error of:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox', AncestorLevel='1'' ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding ElementName=cb}"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Value.DataContext.SubItems, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

`x:Refefrence` comes from this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446923/5615980). However, this answer is not enough. In fact, you need a proxy as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32879146/5615980).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the CellTemplate and EditTemplate for that Template column, you can bind the different itemssources in combobox column.

Please refer the below link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/4896/how-to-bind-different-itemssources-to-each-row-of-the-combobox-by-using-gridtemplatecolumn-in-the