# Why the TargetedTriggerAction's TargetObject is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, datatrigger, eventtrigger

I have three Buttons (1.Male,2.Femal,3.OK),I want to change the `CommandParameters` Property of Button(OK) by Click **Male Button** or **FeMale Button**. I found the question [Setting a property with an EventTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38033794/1616023) is very helpful to me, but the `TargetObject` of `TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>` in `void Invoke(object parameter){...}` function is always `null`, **WHY** ?

**HOW Can I to solve the Problem?**
[image]
[image]

Error info in output window.

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=OKGenderButton'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'SetterAction' (HashCode=20203785); target property is 'TargetObject' (type 'Object')`

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicated, bindingExpression has no path. Try to add a Path

```
{Binding Path=OKGenderButton }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question [ElementName Binding is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122644/1616023)mentioned,

The code `Source={x:Reference DisplayMarkers}` works

Demo Code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                        Content="FeMale"
                        Margin="0 0 90 0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Width="93"
                        Height="93"
                        Style="{DynamicResource FemaleButton}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <triggerActions:SetterAction PropertyName="CommandParameter"
                                                         TargetObject="{x:Reference OKGenderButton}"
                                                         Value="{x:Static constants:Genders.FeMale}" />

                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
```