WPF binding to ElementName in DataTemplate works but in Style Setter not
Can anyone tell me why this code:
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Content_Test1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="Button1">Mouse me</Button>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1"  Margin="2,0,0,0">
                                        HELLO WOLRD
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Content_Test1}">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>



Works.
But this code:
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl1">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button x:Name="Button1">Mouse me</Button>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1"  Margin="2,0,0,0">
                            HELLO WOLRD
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"> <!--Look Here-->
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>


Says:
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Button1'
The task in these two examples is the same, but in the second example, Binding cannot find the ElementName of its own neighboring element, Button1.
So, I'm curious, in the context of this specific task, why does the DataTemplate Binding work, but the Style Setter Binding does not.

What is the reasoning for the ContentControl Style in the first place? You may assign the StackPanel directly to the Content like <ContentControl><StackPanel>...</StackPanel></ContentControl>. Also note that the first DataTrigger is redundant.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122592/elementname-binding-is-failing

@Clemens I am studying the workings and peculiarities of Bindings inside Style Setter selectively. The example above is adapted exclusively for this question.

And you do understand that a Style Setter does not constitute a namescope?

@Clemens I can understand that Style does not implement namescope externally, but within its own hierarchy?

Style setters don't provide a namescope. You are currently referencing a child element of the Style.Setter property from a Style.
Style.Setter is a property and not an object. Only objects can provide a namescope if that makes sense. The next object in the hierarchy is the StackPanel and that doesn't provide a namescope by default.
In WPF, only visual root elements like Page or Window define a namescope. In addition, Style and FrameworkTemplate are able to provide a namescope too, although their namescopes are treated specially in that they allow registered names to exist multiple times (for each context they are applied).
Other than that, no objects provide a namescope by default. You can create namescopes explicitly. See WPF XAML Namescopes to learn more about namescopes.

So binding inside Style to ElementName is dead issue?

Inside a Style you can bind to any named element as a Style is by default a namescope provider. But properties don't provide a namescope. E.g., Button.Content = new StackPanel() { Name = "RootPanel" } won't enable any referencing of the StackPanel by name because Button.Content is a property and not an object. In addition, Button is not a namescope provider by default. It is not able to register names. The next parent that can register names is probably a Window or a Page. But these are not reachable from a property as properties don't participate in the element tree.
